# Q: Tensorflow: how to save/restore tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, save, dataset, restore

I made a model with `tf.data.Dataset()` as a data IO function

then i exported the graph and tried to restore it with meta_graph file
But it failed and following error messages occurred.

I think that `tf.data.Dataset()` made a C++ object instead of python queue used before.

And the `graph_def` only has a C++ object handler reference, so the `graph_def` alone without real C++ object can't load complete graph.

How can I load a executable graph with `tf.data.Dataset()`?
Or is it impossible for now?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Function
_make_dataset_5150cb86 is not defined.
         [[Node: batch_processing/OneShotIterator = OneShotIterator[container="", dataset_factory=_make_dataset_5150cb86[], output_shapes=[[?,1], [?,299,299,3]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT], shared_name="",
_device="/job:workers/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: The `tf.data` APIs add nodes to the graph, you don't need to do anything special to execute graphs that contain them. You might want to add more information to your question (code to reproduce the problem, more details of the stack trace etc.)

Comment: The codes reproducing the problem is too long. 
In short, all the tensorflow graphs without `tf.data.Dataset` work, when i add following code. 


`graph = tf.train.export_meta_graph();
tf.reset_default_graph();
tf.train.import_meta_graph(graph)`


But the graphs with `tf.data.Dataset` make a error message above